# Import part of an audio file in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a .wav audio file of X seconds and I would like to resize this sample in order to delete 5secs each from the beginning and the end.

Is it possible? I tried to figure it out by using

```
 [Y, FS]=audioread(FILENAME, [START END]) and  info = audioinfo(filename)
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you load in the audio file with `audioread` you have the samples Y and the Sampling frequency FS - 5 seconds refers to 5 * FS samples you want to remove from your audio samples so just do something like:

```
[Y, FS]=audioread(FILENAME);
discard = 5 * FS;
newY = Y(discard+1:end-discard);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.